# vectorize conditional assignment in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, vectorization

If I have a dataframe `df` with column `x` and want to create column `y` based on values of `x` using this in pseudo code:

```
if df['x'] < -2 then df['y'] = 1 
else if df['x'] > 2 then df['y'] = -1 
else df['y'] = 0
```

How would I achieve this?  I assume `np.where` is the best way to do this but not sure how to code it correctly.

Comment: Note, there is going to be an additional way to do this with the assign() method in pandas 16.0 (due any day now?) similar to dplyr mutate:  http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/whatsnew.html#dataframe-assign

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19913845) using `np.where` for two choices and `np. select` for more choices.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

One simple method would be to assign the default value first and then perform 2 `loc` calls:

```
In [66]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[0,-3,5,-1,1]})
df
Out[66]:
   x
0  0
1 -3
2  5
3 -1
4  1

In [69]:

df['y'] = 0
df.loc[df['x'] < -2, 'y'] = 1
df.loc[df['x'] > 2, 'y'] = -1
df
Out[69]:
   x  y
0  0  0
1 -3  1
2  5 -1
3 -1  0
4  1  0
```

If you wanted to use `np.where` then you could do it with a nested `np.where`:

```
In [77]:

df['y'] = np.where(df['x'] < -2 , 1, np.where(df['x'] > 2, -1, 0))
df
Out[77]:
   x  y
0  0  0
1 -3  1
2  5 -1
3 -1  0
4  1  0
```

So here we define the first condition as where x is less than -2, return 1, then we have another `np.where` which tests the other condition where x is greater than 2 and returns -1, otherwise return 0

**timings**

```
In [79]:

%timeit df['y'] = np.where(df['x'] < -2 , 1, np.where(df['x'] > 2, -1, 0))

1000 loops, best of 3: 1.79 ms per loop

In [81]:

%%timeit
df['y'] = 0
df.loc[df['x'] < -2, 'y'] = 1
df.loc[df['x'] > 2, 'y'] = -1

100 loops, best of 3: 3.27 ms per loop
```

So for this sample dataset the `np.where` method is twice as fast

Answer (score 10):

#### Use [`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) for multiple conditions

> `np.select(condlist, choicelist, default=0)`
>
> - Return elements in `choicelist` depending on the corresponding condition in `condlist`.
> - The `default` element is used when all conditions evaluate to `False`.

```
condlist = [
    df['x'] < -2,
    df['x'] > 2,
]
choicelist = [
    1,
    -1,
]
df['y'] = np.select(condlist, choicelist, default=0)
```

[`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) is much more readable than a nested `np.where` but just as fast:

[image]

<sup>*`df = pd.DataFrame({'x': np.random.randint(-5, 5, size=n)})`*</sup>

Answer (score 5):

This is a good use case for `pd.cut` where you define ranges and based on those `ranges` you can assign `labels`:

```
df['y'] = pd.cut(df['x'], [-np.inf, -2, 2, np.inf], labels=[1, 0, -1], right=False)
```

**Output**

```
   x  y
0  0  0
1 -3  1
2  5 -1
3 -1  0
4  1  0
```

Comment: I like this answer, but it is slower than the np.where option, based on %timeit on my machine

Answer (score 0):

## set fixed value to 'c2' where the condition is met

```
 df.loc[df['c1'] == 'Value', 'c2'] = 10
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it easily using the index and 2 `loc` calls:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[0,-3,5,-1,1]})

df

   x
0  0
1 -3
2  5
3 -1
4  1
    
df['y'] = 0
idx_1 = df.loc[df['x'] < -2, 'y'].index
idx_2 = df.loc[df['x'] >  2, 'y'].index
df.loc[idx_1, 'y'] =  1
df.loc[idx_2, 'y'] = -1

df

   x  y
0  0  0
1 -3  1
2  5 -1
3 -1  0
4  1  0
```

Comment: Isn't this just a more verbose and probably slower way to write the [existing accepted answer from 3 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28896853/6243352)? There's no need for another layer of `.loc` calls which then need to be `.index`ed.

Comment: Because it works, is the way I use it, is updated, probably easier to understand.