# Pandas: Ternary conditional operator for setting a value in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe `pd`. I would like to change a value of column `irr` depending on whether it is above or below a thresh hold.

How can  I do this in a single line? Now I have

```
pd['irr'] = pd['irr'][pd['cs']*0.63 > pd['irr']] = 1.0
pd['irr'] = pd['irr'][pd['cs']*0.63 <=  pd['irr']] = 0.0
```

The problem of course is that I change `irr` and check it again in the next line.

Is there something like a ternary conditional operator for pandas?

Comment: Related: [vectorize conditional assignment in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28896769/vectorize-conditional-assignment-in-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In pandas no, in numpy yes.

You can use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) or convert `boolean Series` created by condition to `float` - `True`s are `1.0` and `False`s are `0.0`:

```
pd['irr'] = np.where(pd['cs']*0.63 > pd['irr'], 1.0, 0.0)
```

Or:

```
pd['irr'] = (pd['cs']*0.63 > pd['irr']).astype(float)
```

Sample:

```
pd = pd.DataFrame({'cs':[1,2,5],
                   'irr':[0,100,0.04]})

print (pd)
   cs     irr
0   1    0.00
1   2  100.00
2   5    0.04

pd['irr'] = (pd['cs']*0.63 > pd['irr']).astype(float)
print (pd)
   cs  irr
0   1  1.0
1   2  0.0
2   5  1.0
```

Comment: You say "pandas no", but it seems like you show how to do it in pandas.  Is that only because OP wanted 0/1, and we can convert `bool` to the desired output?  But we don't have a true ternary operation in general?

Comment: Doesn´t this method raise the `SettingWithCopyWarning`?