# numpy where: add value where

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this data frame:

```
           ticker                   value short
0  APPL US Equity    Quarterly and Annual      
1  TTMT IN Equity    Quarterly and Annual      
2   BUD US Equity  Semi-Annual and Annual      
3    PS US Equity                  Annual
```

I want this:

```
           ticker                   value short
0  APPL US Equity    Quarterly and Annual      
1  TTMT IN Equity    Quarterly and Annual      
2   BUD US Equity  Semi-Annual and Annual      
3    PS US Equity                  Annual  A
```

here is my attempt:

```
dfx['short'] = dfx[np.where(dfx['value'].strip() == 'Annual','A'
                                    ,dfx['short'])]
```

this works:

```
dfx['short'] = np.where(dfx['value'] == 'Annual','A',dfx['short'])
```

Comment: remove the `dfx[...]` on the right hand side of the equal sign: `dfx['short'] = np.where(dfx['value'].strip() == 'Annual','A',dfx['short'])`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas: Ternary conditional operator for setting a value in a DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46525270/pandas-ternary-conditional-operator-for-setting-a-value-in-a-dataframe)

Answer (score 1):

You can set a only part of the values in a column with .loc:

```
mask = dfx['value'].strip() == 'Annual'
dfx.loc[mask, 'short'] = 'A'
```