# ternary operator in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am doing the following exercise and I have some part of it

Create a new column with a 1 if the country's % Renewable value is at or above the median for all countries in the top 15, and a 0 if the country's % Renewable value is below the median.

My code:

```
df = answer_one()
print(df)
mean = df['#% Renewable'].mean()
df['ratio'] = df['#% Renewable'] > mean
```

I want to know if there is a way to create in one line a ternary operator, something like:

```
If renewable > mean then 0 if renewable < mean then 1.
```

but not sure how to achieve this on python in one line

Comment: `result = 0 if renewable>mean else 1`

Comment: What do you want to do if renewable == mean? (asking Luis not sahasrara)

Comment: with a 1 if the country's % Renewable value is at or above

Comment: @sahasrara62 this doesnt work,   df['ratio'] = 0 if df['% Renewable']>mean else 1, I get this error: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas: Ternary conditional operator for setting a value in a DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46525270/pandas-ternary-conditional-operator-for-setting-a-value-in-a-dataframe)

Comment: TL;DR - `df['ratio'] = np.where(df['#% Renewable'] > mean, 1, 0)`

Comment: median is the middle number versus mean which is the average of the numbers