# How to add a dataframe date column calculated from an existing date column and a criteria column?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, timedelta

I have the following dataframe.
The dates are `dtype='datetime64[ns, UTC]'`

```
    announce_date  announce_time
0   2013-01-23     After Market Close
1   2013-04-23     Before Market Open
2   2013-07-20     After Market Close
```

How do I create a new column that offsets
`announce_date` by 1 if `announce_time` is `"After Market Close"`.

```
    announce_date  announce_time          impact_date
0   2013-01-23     After Market Close     2013-01-24
1   2013-04-23     Before Market Open     2013-04-23
2   2013-07-20     After Market Close     2013-07-21
```

I can do an offset date column but haven't figure out how to apply the condition.

```
import pandas as pd

df['impact_date'] = df['announce_date'] + pd.DateOffset(days=1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generate a boolean mask and generate offsets from it using `pd.to_timedelta`.

```
# Convert "announce_date" to datetime if not already done.
# df['announce_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['announce_date'], errors='coerce')
# Now calculate the offset.
offset = pd.to_timedelta(
    df['announce_time'].eq("After Market Close").astype(int), unit='D')    
df['impact_date'] = df['announce_date'] + offset

print(df)
  announce_date       announce_time impact_date
0    2013-01-23  After Market Close  2013-01-24
1    2013-04-23  Before Market Open  2013-04-23
2    2013-07-20  After Market Close  2013-07-21
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks coldspeed. 

Answer (score 1):

You can use [np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

> df['impact_date'] = df['announce_date'] +
>   np.where(df['announce_time']=="After Market Close",pd.DateOffset(days=1),pd.DateOffset(days=0))

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28896769/vectorize-conditional-assignment-in-pandas-dataframe) has detailed explanation.

Comment: Thanks Sach. I swear I tried this approach and it didn't work.   
For anyone playing along this works but throws a warning. `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/ops.py:477: PerformanceWarning: Adding/subtracting array of DateOffsets to Series not vectorized
  "Series not vectorized", PerformanceWarning)`

Comment: @GollyJer If you're generating a series of timedeltas, the recommended method of doing so is using `pd.to_timedelta`. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could just create a while loop traversing through the announce_time like this...

```
count = 0
list1 = []
while count != len(df):
    if df.iloc[count,1] == 'After Market Close':
        list1.append(df.iloc[count,0] + pd.DateOffset(days=1))
        count += 1
    else:
        list1.append(df.iloc[count,0])
        count += 1

df['impact_date'] = list1
```

Comment: Thanks Drew. This approach can be useful with multiple criteria as well.