# How do I change the values of a column with respect to certain conditions using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

The data frame contains 5 columns named V, W, X, Y, Z.

I'm supposed to change the values in column X from a dataset according to:

- if 1 to 100, change to 1
- if 101 to 200, change to 2
- if 201 to 300, change to 3

otherwise, change to 4

What's the most efficient way this can be done?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html.  What have you tried?

Comment: using `pd.cut`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57208910/6660373

Comment: This question is unclear and could really use some sample data; it's unclear if X is an index or a column (you state both...)

Comment: repeated. Check this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31511997/pandas-dataframe-replace-all-values-in-a-column-based-on-condition) and please next time research a little bit before posting.

Comment: @Pygirl no, since I need these values to replace the ones in X, not create another column

Comment: @ALollz sorry, editted it out. I got confused with the question for a second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an example `df` and @Pygirl's idea:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.random.randint(0, 400, 10), 'b': np.random.randint(0, 400, 10), 'X': np.zeros(10)})
```

gives us:

```
|    |   a |   b |   X |
|---:|----:|----:|----:|
|  0 | 237 | 188 |   0 |
|  1 | 212 | 147 |   0 |
|  2 | 135 |  30 |   0 |
|  3 | 296 | 154 |   0 |
|  4 | 133 | 219 |   0 |
|  5 | 185 | 317 |   0 |
|  6 | 365 |   5 |   0 |
|  7 | 108 | 189 |   0 |
|  8 | 358 |  34 |   0 |
|  9 | 105 |   2 |   0 |
```

with `pd.cut` [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) we can get:

```
df['X'] = pd.cut(df.a, [0, 100, 200, 300, np.inf], labels=[1, 2, 3, 4])
```

which results in:

```
|    |   a |   b |   X |
|---:|----:|----:|----:|
|  0 | 377 | 232 |   4 |
|  1 |  61 |  11 |   1 |
|  2 |  52 | 217 |   1 |
|  3 | 191 |  42 |   2 |
|  4 | 178 | 228 |   2 |
|  5 | 235 | 206 |   3 |
|  6 |  39 | 222 |   1 |
|  7 | 316 | 210 |   4 |
|  8 | 135 | 390 |   2 |
|  9 |  44 | 311 |   1 |
```