# Pandas: Replacing values with np.nan in Column A depending on value in column B

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
    wavelength  normalized flux lof
0   5100.00 0.948305    1
1   5100.07 0.796783    1
2   5100.14 0.696425    1
3   5100.21 0.880586    1
4   5100.28 0.836257    1
... ... ... ...
4281    5399.67 1.076449    1
4282    5399.74 1.038198    1
4283    5399.81 1.004292    1
4284    5399.88 0.946977    1
4285    5399.95 0.894559    1
```

If `lof = -1`, I want to replace the normalized flux value with `np.nan`. Otherwise, just leave the normalized flux value as is. Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just assign

```
df.loc[df['lof']==-1,'flux'] = np.nan
```

Comment: I think we can close as dupe? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28896769/vectorize-conditional-assignment-in-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 0):

```
df['flux']=df['flux'].mask(df['lof'].eq(-1), np.nan)
df
```

Comment: Please avoid providing code-only answers without an explanation on why your code resolves the question. While the code may solve the problem, the answer is not useful in understanding why it solves it.